# How can I connect my Node.js application to MongoDB without using native modules?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We can accept 20 times slower to avoid using python or C++ in our project. Are there a native module that still works?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to invent wheel. [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) package is the simplest one

But if You insist there are many ways:

**Easy way:** You can use Rest API of mongo and do requests to it using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package

**Moderate way:** Open [mongodb-core](https://github.com/christkv/mongodb-core) package and copy out what You need most, make Your own mongodb class.

**Moderate way #2:** fork [mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) package, manipulate it and save with new repository name

**Hard way:** If You want go hardcore (: read mongodb protocol and operate with it using [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) package to open socket connection to mongodb server.

Comment: So there isn't anyone already reinvented the wheels? Ah... T_T

Comment: I'm also inventing sometimes, but after a while I understand that it's time waste. If there is working packages, why I need to waste my time to making new one? You can do following: fork mongodb package, manipulate it and save with new name.

Comment: Personally if I'm working with MongoDB I prefer to use the [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) ORM. It just works and I love the way they have you method chain queries. Reminds me of using LINQ to Entities in C#.

Comment: @Chev I'm also using mongoose in my projects. But in case of low level code I recommend SCLeo to have a look to native packages.

Comment: @Chev Thanks for mentioning Mongoose. I am going to use that. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about [Crest](https://github.com/cordazar/crest)? It's a node wrapper around the MongoDB server that provides a REST API. With it you could talk to MongoDB over REST instead of with a native client, similar to CouchDB.

There are some other utilities listed [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/). Maybe you're okay with using Python outside of your app but in front of MongoDB to provide the REST API? If so then maybe those are some alternatives if you don't like Crest. Haven't used it myself so I can't vouch for its quality, but it is listed on MongoDB's own list so hopefully it's decent.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not have a detailed document. At least I cannot find. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Np. If you're not willing to wrap the MongoDB server with something to provide an API easier to consume in native node then I think your only bet is to literally talk to the MongoDB server with your own socket. @num8er's answer mentions the same thing. That's gonna be a lot of work though.

Comment: Another alternative is to switch to CouchDB ;)

Comment: Never heard of CouchBase. Is it related to CouchDB?

Comment: @Chev :) ohh... my mistake.  But I like CouchBase after MongoDB.

Comment: I love CouchDB for web development. It's built around REST natively so you don't need a wrapper like you would for MongoDB. You can interact with the [raw REST API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/index.html) which is actually pretty easy. Or if you want even easier you can use a very tiny node module called [nano](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#getting-started) which just wraps [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and does the lower level http request work for you.